# Как заставить Qpainter рисовать на нужном виджете.

Tags: qt, c++

Есть форма, на которой много чего, включая один пустой виджет graphArea. QPainter создается следующим образом:

```
fPainter = new QPainter(ui->graphArea);
```

После чего рисую прямоугольник:

```
fPainter->begin(this);
fPainter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

fPainter->setBrush(QColor(255,255,255));
fPainter->drawRect(0,0,ui->graphArea->width(),ui->graphArea->height());
fPainter->end();
```

А рисуется он начиная от левого верхнего угла формы, а не на виджете.
Как заставить его рисовать на виджете? На чем вообще лучше рисовать?

**UPD:** По совету @1101_debian пытаюсь рисовать теперь на QGraphicsView.
Вот весь код `paintEvent`:
    fPainter = new QPainter(this);
    QGraphicsView *pGraphArea = ui->graphArea;

```
fPainter->begin(pGraphArea);
fPainter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

fPainter->setPen(Qt::black);
fPainter->drawRect(pGraphArea->x(),pGraphArea->y(),pGraphArea->width(),pGraphArea->height());

for (int i= pGraphArea->x(); i < pGraphArea->width(); i += 96/2.54)
    for (int j = pGraphArea->y(); j < pGraphArea->height(); j += 96/2.54)
         fPainter->drawPoint(i,j);

fPainter->end();
event->ignore();
```

Получилось вот так:
[image]

т.е. рисуется, но опять же за пределами QGraphicsView. Что не так делаю?

Comment: Немного не так. Нужно создать сцену, затем создать объект сцены (прямоугольник, линию и .п.) и добавить на сцену, а затем установить эту сцену в QGraphicsView через метод setScene.

Comment: Ааа! Попробую.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте передать в fPainter->begin ваш виджет на котором вы хотите рисовать.

```
fPainter->begin(ui->graphArea);
```

А вообще я бы для этого использовал [QGraphicsScene](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qgraphicsscene.html) и [QGraphicsView](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qgraphicsview.html).

**UPD.**
[Официальный мануал](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.7/graphicsview.html#id-3d7ed173-a418-4f89-be26-3b0f816e1341) от Nokia

Comment: Да мануал-то я видел. Не особо понимаю что не так делаю(

Comment: Получилось нарисовать как надо рамку вот так:

    QGraphicsView *pGraphArea = ui->graphArea;
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    pGraphArea->setScene(scene);            scene->addRect(QRect(10,10,pGraphArea->width()-20,pGraphArea->height()- 20));`

А как нарисовать сетку из точек? QPainter теперь не нужен?

Comment: что вы подразумеваете под сеткой?

Comment: Нужно нарисовать последовательность точек с некоторым интервалом. Проблема не в этом. Как в принципе нарисовать точку?

Comment: Т.е. график? Используйте для этого QGraphicsPolygonItem, ему можно передать QPolygonF, который в свою очередь состоит из набора точек QPointF. Пролистайте внимательней манула, там ниже ссылки на классы.

Answer (score 0):

Вы про это или нет, но у `QWidget` есть такой классный метод, как `render()`:

```
void QWidget::render(
    QPaintDevice * target,
    const QPoint & targetOffset = QPoint(),
    const QRegion & sourceRegion = QRegion(),
    RenderFlags renderFlags = RenderFlags(DrawWindowBackground | DrawChildren)
)
```

Самое прямое применение (пример из Qt Assistant):

```
QPainter painter(this);
// ...
painter.end();
myWidget->render(this);
```

Рисует или нет не проверял, но весь виджет в `QPainter` передаётся исправно.
Лично я передавал на печать(через класс QPrinter) целый виджет:

```
QPrinter *printer = new QPrinter(QPrinter::HighResolution); 
printer->setPageSize(QPrinter::A4);
printer->setOrientation(QPrinter::Portrait);
printer->setPageMargins (15,15,15,15,QPrinter::Millimeter);
printer->setFullPage(true);
printer->setOutputFileName("output.pdf");
printer->setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
QPainter *painter = new QPainter;
painter->begin(printer);
QRect view(0,0,printer->pageRect().width(),printer->paperRect().height());
painter->setViewport(view);
painter->scale(10.0,10.0);
painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
this->render(painter);
painter->end();
```